# C++: Trouble moving cursor to edit command line graphics for a game

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii, refresh

I'm pretty new to coding.

Since *system("cls")* causes my console to flash as it continually deletes and redraws graphics, I am trying to figure out how to create a game without it.

In the code attached below, I try to use two arrays and rewrite only the elements that are different, in order to update the graphics, but for some reason it isn't moving the cursor to the correct position, and doesn't seem to be outputting new graphics either.

I would appreciate it if anyone can explain why it is not working, and show me how to fix it, or provide an alternative method to redraw graphics without them flashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
enum direction {STOP, UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT};
direction dir;
bool gameOver = false;
string test [38];
string display [38];
string futuredisplay [38];
HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//The goal of this program was to refresh my graphics in a more reliable way than using
//system("cls") (because it makes the screen flicker when it clears it and redraws)
//This new code shouldn't do that since it isn't actually clearing the screen just writing over it.
//Unfortunately, the cursor position does seem to change when it tries to write over it, but not
//to the correct location, and doesn't seem to do anything...

//I populate the three arrays of strings I have with #s to represent my rectangular game map.
//For some reason when I try to copy it over Code::Blocks crashes, so I do it manually each time.
//I make 38 strings that are 100 chars long
//and make a boarder of #s.
//Like this but bigger    #######
//                        #     #
//                        #######
void setup ()
{
test[0] = "####################################################################################################";
test[1] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[2] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[3] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[4] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[5] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[6] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[7] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[8] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[9] = "#                                                                                                  #";
test[10]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[11]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[12]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[13]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[14]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[15]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[16]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[17]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[18]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[19]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[20]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[21]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[22]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[23]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[24]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[25]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[26]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[27]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[28]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[29]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[30]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[31]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[32]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[33]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[34]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[35]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[36]= "#                                                                                                  #";
test[37]= "####################################################################################################";

display[0] = "####################################################################################################";
display[1] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[2] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[3] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[4] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[5] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[6] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[7] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[8] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[9] = "#                                                                                                  #";
display[10]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[11]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[12]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[13]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[14]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[15]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[16]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[17]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[18]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[19]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[20]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[21]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[22]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[23]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[24]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[25]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[26]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[27]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[28]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[29]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[30]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[31]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[32]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[33]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[34]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[35]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[36]= "#                                                                                                  #";
display[37]= "####################################################################################################";

futuredisplay[0] = "####################################################################################################";
futuredisplay[1] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[2] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[3] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[4] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[5] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[6] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[7] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[8] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[9] = "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[10]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[11]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[12]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[13]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[14]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[15]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[16]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[17]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[18]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[19]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[20]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[21]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[22]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[23]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[24]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[25]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[26]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[27]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[28]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[29]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[30]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[31]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[32]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[33]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[34]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[35]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[36]= "#                                                                                                  #";
futuredisplay[37]= "####################################################################################################";
//I give the display and future display arrays, an element with the 'o' character to represent my coordinates.
for (int a = 0; a < 38; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++)
{
    if (a == y && b == x)
    {
        display[a][b] = 'o';
        futuredisplay[a][b] = 'o';
    }
}
//I print  the display array.
for (int c = 37; c >=0; c--)
    for (int d = 0; d < 100; d++)
{
    if (d < 99)
    cout << display[c][d];

    else
    cout << display[c][d] << endl;
}

}
void draw()
{
//The objective of this code is to move the cursor and print over any differences between the display and futuredisplay arrays
//Nothing should happen the first time around since they are the same.
for (int y = 0; y < 38; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
    {
        char transitive = display[y][z];
        if (transitive != futuredisplay[y][z])
        {
            COORD pos = {z, y};
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
            cout << futuredisplay[y][z];
        }
    }
//After it writes over the screen, it makes display equal to futuredisplay (which will be changed again in the logic section)
for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++)
    for (int j =0; j < 100; j++)
{
    char transfer = futuredisplay[i][j];
    display[i][j] = transfer;
}
}
//this is standard input
void input()
{
   if (_kbhit())
   {
       switch (_getch())
       {
       case('w'):
       dir = UP;
       break;
       case('a'):
       dir = LEFT;
       break;
       case('s'):
       dir = DOWN;
       break;
       case('d'):
       dir = RIGHT;
       break;
       }
   }
}
//just changes the coordinates of x and y based on input
void logic()
{
switch (dir)
{
case (UP):
y++;
break;
case(DOWN):
y--;
break;
case(LEFT):
x--;
break;
case(RIGHT):
x++;
break;
}
//Once x and y changes, it uses the test array to get rid of the 'o' character in future array and make it barren again.
for (int e = 0; e < 38; e++)
    for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++)
{
    char transfer = test[e][f];
    futuredisplay[e][f] = transfer;
}
//It now adds the new 'o' character based on updated coordinates.
//If all goes according to plan, when this new futuredisplay is compared to display in draw, it will write over it.
for (int g = 0; g < 38; g++)
    for (int h = 0; h < 100; h++)
{
    if (g == y && h == x)
    {
        futuredisplay[g][h] = 'o';
    }
}
}


int main()
{
    setup();
while (gameOver == false)
{
    draw();
    input();
    logic();
}
}
```

Comment: You need to use some system-specific API (such as `WriteConsoleW`) or some library wrapping them to update console view efficiently.

Comment: Update: Problem solved! The issue was that I was using the same coordinate system for navigating the arrays and moving the cursor... but I printed the arrays from their highest to lowest values. So for example, if the new 'o' was at 2,1 in the array, that was actually printed at 35, 1 on the console (since it was printed from top to bottom). Once I fixed that, the only other problem was that the program was running too fast to even see the 'o' move, so I added a sleep. Now It works great, there's no flashing, and its a lot of fun. :D